# Удаление радиокнопок

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Помогите разобраться с удаление радиокнопок Тупо не понимаю как сделать, чтобы удалялись все кнопки, которые были добавлены. При попытке удалить еще один выдается ошибка :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\dmozo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
> line 1699, in __call__ return self.func(*args)
>
> File "C:/Users/dmozo/Desktop/Tester Creater/timer.py", line 12, in b
>     n.destroy()
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'destroy'
> ```

```
from tkinter import *
def a(event):
   global n,h,l,j
   l=l+1
   j=j+50
   n=Radiobutton(root, variable=var, justify=LEFT, font='Sans 20', value=l)
   n.place(x=0, y=j)
   h=h+1
def b(event):
   global n,h,l,j
   n.destroy()
   h=h-1
   l=l-1
   j=j-50
root=Tk()
root.title('Главное меню')
root.geometry('400x400')
label = Label(root,font='Sans 16')
label.pack()
var = IntVar()
var.set(0)
rad0 = Radiobutton(root,  variable=var, justify=LEFT, font='Sans 20', value=1)
rad1 = Radiobutton(root,  variable=var, justify=LEFT, font='Sans 20', value=2)
rad2 = Radiobutton(root, variable=var, justify=LEFT, font='Sans 20', value=3)
h=2
j=100
l=3
n='rad'+str(h)
rad0.place(x=0,y=0)
rad1.place(x=0,y=50)
rad2.place(x=0,y=100)
e=Button(root,text='Далее',font='Sans 16')
e.place(x=50,y=300)
e.bind("<Button-1>",a)
e=Button(root,text='Далее',font='Sans 16')
e.place(x=50,y=200)
e.bind("<Button-1>",b)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: И тогда как иначе сделать. P.s Потому что я могу понять как это переводится мне нужен ответ как это исправить

Comment: если никто раньше не ответит, то я вечером напишу

Comment: Так можно получить желаемый ответ, просто вечер немного прошел а хотя бы немножко нужной информации я не получил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите удалить виджет, то нужно использовать метод `destroy` самого объекта (а не пытаться применить этот метод к строке), т.е. `rad2.destroy()` - сработает, а `'rad2'.destroy()` - нет.

Если вам нужно удалить один из объектов `RadioButton` по его номеру, то лучше поместить все объекты в список, а потом по индексу в списке удалять нужный элемент. Пример:

```
...

def b(event):
   global h,l,j
   rad[h].destroy()
   h=h-1
   l=l-1
   j=j-50

...

rad = [
    Radiobutton(root, variable=var, justify=LEFT, font='Sans 20', value=i+1, text=str(i+1))
    for i in range(3)
]

h=2
j=100
l=3

for i, item in enumerate(rad):
    item.place(x=0, y=i*50)
```

Т.к. вам нужно удалять и добавлять элементы, то нужно соответственно добавлять и удалять их из списка. Можно убрать некоторые лишние глобальные переменные, т.к. можно ориентироваться на длину списка (общее количество элементов). В принципе отступ для нового `RadioButton` сверху (`j` в вашем коде, `rbutton_y` в моем коде ниже) тоже можно рассчитывать от общей длины списка, и никак не хранить. Также рекомендую использовать "говорящие" имена переменных и функций вместо односимвольных. Полный рабочий код:

```
from tkinter import *

def add_rbutton(event):
    global rbutton_y
    rbutton_y += 50
    number = len(rad) + 1
    r = Radiobutton(root, variable=var, justify=LEFT, font='Sans 20', value=number, text=str(number))
    r.place(x=0, y=rbutton_y)
    rad.append(r)

def remove_rbutton(event):
   global rbutton_y
   if rad:  # Проверяем, что список не пустой
       rad[-1].destroy()  # Уничтожаем последний элемент
       rad.pop()  # Удаляем последний (уже уничтоженный) элемент списка
       # Т.к. rad.pop() возвращает удаленный элемент списка, то можно предыдущие две строки записать в одну:
       # rad.pop().destroy()
       rbutton_y -= 50

root=Tk()
root.title('Главное меню')
root.geometry('400x400')
label = Label(root,font='Sans 16')
label.pack()
var = IntVar()
var.set(0)

rad = [
    Radiobutton(root, variable=var, justify=LEFT, font='Sans 20', value=i+1, text=str(i+1))
    for i in range(3)
]

rbutton_y = 100

for i, item in enumerate(rad):
    item.place(x=0, y=i*50)

button = Button(root,text='Далее',font='Sans 16')
button.place(x=50,y=300)
button.bind("<Button-1>", add_rbutton)

button = Button(root,text='Далее',font='Sans 16')
button.place(x=50,y=200)
button.bind("<Button-1>", remove_rbutton)

root.mainloop()
```